# Блок с информацией занял всю ширину

Tags: css, html5, flexbox, blocks

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка в коде? Надо чтобы было как на картинке, но в браузере блок с ценой расположен под блоком с информацией.

```css
.wrapper{
 max-width: 1250px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px 40px;
}

.service-list_item h6{
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.service-list_item p{
 color: #737373;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 28px;
}

.box-pricing{
 display: flex;
}

.box-pricing .service-list_icon{
 margin-left: 0;
 height: 125px;
 width: 125px;
 font-size: 32px;
}

.pricing{
 display: flex;
 text-align: center;
}

.pricing-item{
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.pricing-item:first-child{
 border-right: none;
}

.pricing-item:last-child{
 border-left: none;
}

.pricing-header{
 padding: 25px 28px;
}

.pricing-header_title{
 color: #0d0d0d;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.pricing-header_title span::before{
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #f39c12;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-pricing">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="service-list_item">
    <div class="service-list_icon"><span class="icon-banknote"></span></div>
    <h6>Packege Pricing</h6>
    <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec 
    sagittis sem nibh id elit. </p>
   </div>

   <div class="pricing">
    <div class="pricing-item">
     <div class="pricing-header">
      <span class="pricing-header_title">Basic 
       <span class="">$35</span>
      </span>
     </div>
     <ul class="pricing-list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="pricing-footer"><a href="#" class="btn"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-item">
     <div class="pricing-header">
      <span class="pricing-header_title">Gold 
       <span class="">$99</span>
      </span>
     </div>
     <ul class="pricing-list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="pricing-footer"><a href="#" class="btn"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-item">
     <div class="pricing-header">
      <span class="pricing-header_title">Silver
       <span class="">$65</span>
      </span>
     </div>
     <ul class="pricing-list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="pricing-footer"><a href="#" class="btn"></a></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавь `display:flex` к .wrapper.

Comment: и justify-content: space-between

Comment: Не подходит, враппер применяется ко всем блокам на странице, и тогда они начинают "съезжать".

Comment: Ну тогда оберните service-list_item и pricing в отдельный блок и задайте ему flex

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}

.service-list_item h6 {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.service-list_item p {
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.box-pricing {
  display: flex;
}

.box-pricing .service-list_icon {
  margin-left: 0;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.pricing {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.pricing-item:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.pricing-item:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.pricing-header {
  padding: 25px 28px;
}

.pricing-header_title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.pricing-header_title span::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #f39c12;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-pricing">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="service-list_item">
      <div class="service-list_icon"><span class="icon-banknote"></span></div>
      <h6>Packege Pricing</h6>
      <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing">
      <div class="pricing-item">
        <div class="pricing-header">
          <span class="pricing-header_title">Basic 
       <span class="">$35</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul class="pricing-list">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pricing-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-item">
        <div class="pricing-header">
          <span class="pricing-header_title">Gold 
       <span class="">$99</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul class="pricing-list">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pricing-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-item">
        <div class="pricing-header">
          <span class="pricing-header_title">Silver
       <span class="pricing-item_price">$65</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <ul class="pricing-list">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pricing-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```